# Should security updates always be installed?

Tags: security

We are a small shop, with no real sysadmin. So developers (Java EE) also try to maintain Ubuntu server 12.04.

When I login a terminal and I see messages like:

```
6 packages can be updated.
6 updates are security updates.
```

Should all security updates always be installed? Can some be ignored? 
Should these be acted upon immediately? Or one could wait for 2:00 a.m. on the coming Sunday? Is there a way to know a "critical" update?

Is there a good sysadmin for dummies resource I should be reading?

Comment: I agree with what others have said below. I just want to add that when you see *6* packages that can be updated, and are security updates, 99 times out of 100, it will be an updated kernel. This means you need to update with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: 'Yes', and pretty much always.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/27418/what-is-a-security-update

Comment: @reverendj1: 99% of the time? Where do you get that statistic? In my experience, security updates come more than once a week, whereas kernel updates come rarely.

Comment: @paddy landau - Yes. I am the admin for between 30 and 40 Ubuntu servers at work. EVERY time I've seen exactly 6 security updates it has been because of a kernel update.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generally security updates are about fixing serious BUGS in the current Ubuntu OS regarding Network, Security and all. If you are maintaining a web server or any web related things, then you **must** have them to be safe.

For example see here some issues: [Ubuntu security notices | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/)

Answer (score 17):

If you're going to hold back any updates, I wouldn't hold back security updates.

There's a reason the server install has an install-time option of "automatically download and install only security related updates"